# Is it possible to use the blur behind Core Animation(effect) on an NSPanel?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, core-graphics, transparency, nspanel

The context menu from dock items is not only translucent but also blurs the contents behind it, Is this effect availible for translucent floating panels? This is the same effect used in Sheet Alert dialogs (e.g. quit with unsaved changes) but in that case the transparency is different, and the background is light rather than dark

[image]

Some background, we have a pro app that is frequently used full screen, and our floating palettes have some transparency, but obviously the more transparency we have the harder it is to read the text on them when the background is very active/noisy, if we could have a slight blur we would be able to greatly improve the readability on the text while still allowing some context of "whats behind the palette"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want: [Using Core Image Filters On/Under a NSWindow](http://iloveco.de/using-core-image-filters-onunder-a-nswindow/)

Beware that this is private API though, so if you're developing for the Mac App Store, this would be a problem.